# iOS: Provisioning profile missing private key?

Tags: ios, xcode

In my Keychain, I have my iOS developer certificate, along with its nested private key.

In the Apple developer center, I created a provisioning profile under Distribution for my app, and downloaded it. When I bring it into Xcode, I see the provisioning profile but it says "valid signing identity not found" and I can't properly build an archive for ad hoc distribution.

How can I resolve this? Like I said, under my Keychain, I have my private key AND my developer profile certificate.

Comment: are you sure the provisioning profile you created was signed with the specific certificate that you downloaded?

Comment: How can I make sure of this? I don't know how to sign provisioning profiles

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the apple developer's Certificates, Identifiers and Profiles section, you have an option to generate a certificate for ad-hoc or app store. After selection that, you should have to create a signing request such as this screen...

[image: CSR screenshot]

once you created a certificate, then proceed to create a provisioning profile with THAT certificate.

Comment: Ah, so if the production certificate was created by a coworker, I'd need that private key for the production cert before creating my own provisioning profile, correct?

Comment: Yes - you can probably get them to export it and you might be ok.

Answer (score 1):

When you were creating your provisioning profile in the provisioning portal your first step would have been to select Distribution or Development (you selected Distribution).

Then in the second step you were supposed to select app ID (make sure this app ID matches the bundle ID of your app).

Then on the next screen you select the certificate with which to sign this provisioning profile. Make sure this is the same certificate that you downloaded. It needs to be a special distribution certificate that you would have created beforehand. Note the name and the expiration date of the certificate, then download this certificate from the Production section in Certificates.

Answer (score 0):

There are some few steps to get it working:

1. Request a certificate from Keychain Access -> Certificate Assistant
2. Add iOS Certificate from developer.apple.com -> Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles -> Certificates
3. Download that certificate
4. Then add iOS Provisioning Profiles with that Certificate

It worked for me.